# NAS (with qt/linux)- Cannot establish simple audio server connection test

Tags: c++, linux, qt, audio, nas

I have the following test code set up, trying to play a simple wav, which errors out on "Can't connect to audio server".

```
static AuServer  *server = 0;
server = AuOpenServer("", 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
if (!server)
{
     fprintf(stderr, "Can't connect to audio server\n");
     exit(-1);
}
AuSoundPlayFromFile(server, "/public/sounds/test-tone.wav", 
AuNone,100, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

System specs:
-linux
-redhat 7.2 on VB
-QT 4.8.5 using c++

This issue could be due to improperly setting up NAS. I had to install the following rpms on my compiler and in my VB:

```
nas-libs-1.9.3-3.fc18.i686 
nas-devel-1.9.3-3.fc18.i686
nas-debuginfo-1.9.3-3.fc18.i686
```

anything else i'd need to do? linux doesnt recognoze the command "nasd". what am i missing?

I'm asking for knowledge on why the above code does not work, background information on how NAS works and what the purpose of the audio server is, and any other thoughts moving forward to find a library that I have access to that can play a wav. Also I have only seen the MAN page as documentation for NAS, any other relevant doc links would be appreciated.

the following is about all I have to go on for documentation:
https://linux.die.net/man/3/ausoundplayfromfile

https://linux.die.net/man/3/auopenserver

---

**Background info**

***Other options explored***
I have dabbled with QSound, Phonon, and now NAS (Network Audio System) and reached varying roadblocks with each. My project cannot easily use library's not already installed or not included in QT4 core.

**QSound:** I have been unable to get to play any of my test wavs. From my research QSound somehow uses NAS, so maybe an improper NAS setup could also be failing Qsound? Hard to say with so little Qsound options and since I hear its beyond buggy.

**Phonon:** having compilation issues from .pro finding -lphonon. possibly due to installing the wrong bit phonon RPMS. installed 64 bit, but cannot install the 32 bit with tons of dependency issues out of my league.While fellow developers say to use 32 bit, System claims to be 64 with "arch" command, so I'm confused to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out QTMultiMedia is actually available in qt4.8 and it works for me!Its low level and doesn't seem as common in 4.8 due to phonon still being available. Still not sure what the issue was with NAS, but I recommend looking into QTMultiMedia if anyone finds themselves here with similar circumstances.

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtmultimedia-module.html